# Чётные и нечётные числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

задача: напиши программу, которая записывает в первый файл все чётные числа до 100, а во второй все нечётные.

что у меня получилось:

```
i = 1
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
while i <= 100:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sum1 += i
    else:
        sum2 += i
    i +=1
print ('Четная сумма от 1 до 100:% d'% sum1)
print ('Нечетная сумма от 1 до 100:% d'% sum2)
```

Помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: Что за жалобный стиль?:-) Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: ошибки нету. нужно чтобы в файл записывались чётные числа до 100 а во второй все нечётные. звучит просто а разобраться не могу

Comment: судя по условию задачи надо вывести сами числа, а не их суммы. А тогда, вам нужно вместо, например, `sum1 += i` написать вывод числа `i` в файл1. Аналогично вместо  `sum2 += i` вывод в файл2.

Comment: Прочитайте тему "работа с файлами" и сделайте. Вот этого достаточно: <https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html>

Comment: А вопрос вообще в чём состоит? Есть задача – решайте.

Comment: вопрос в том как решить задачу, у меня не очень получается как видите

Comment: Но на будущее - не прикладывайте к вопросу левый код, не имеющий отношения к задаче. Лучше хоть что-то самому попытаться, но по делу )

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 1
f =  open('четное.txt', 'wt')
g = open('нечетное.txt', 'wt')
while i <= 100:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        f.write(str(i) + '\n')
        print(f"четное: {i}")
    else:
        g.write(str(i) + '\n')
        print(f"нечетное: {i}")
    i +=1
```

всем спасибо кто не скинул готовый код(честно, спасибо) так я хоть пошевелил мозгами)

Comment: ну вот, видите:-) Только лучше всё же закрывать файлы ещё командой.

Answer (score 1):

```py
count = 100

f1 = open("file1.txt", "a")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "a")

for num in range(1, count + 1):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        f1.write(str(num) + "\n")
    else:
        f2.write(str(num) + "\n")

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Не надо делать чужую "домашку" на этом сайте, пожалуйста. Люди сами должны учиться.

Comment: если готовое решение не копировать в тупую, а изучить, можно понять как всё работает

Comment: Даня, это нужно по документации изучать. Не тот уровень сложности. Там же не программа с ошибками была, а просто незаконченный код. И ещё раз, я вам написал, как в целом принято на этом сайте действовать. На "Решалке" -по-другому.

Comment: ну к примеру он увидел не знакомую конструкцию range() и загуглил что это такое, в любом случае пример того, как другой человек реализовал ту же задачу никогда лишним не будет

Comment: @Сергей на сайте нет такого правила, запрещающего помогать участникам, "чтобы они сами учились". Тем более что свою попытку решения человек предоставил. Минусование рабочих ответов - это вообще маразм.

Comment: @insolor, 1) не было там попытки вывода в файл. Я об этом в комментариях написал, дав ссылку, что смотреть. 2) запрета нет, но говорится "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос." => не рекомендуется отвечать на вопрос без попытки.

Comment: @Сергей, 2.1 - запрета нет, значит отвечать можно. 2.2 - автор пытался решить самостоятельно. 2.3 - "не рекомендуется отвечать на вопрос без попытки." - это ваши домыслы. Между "не рекомендуется задавать вопросы без самостоятельной попытки решения" и "не рекомендуется отвечать на такие вопросы" нет логической связи. Второе не следует из первого. Там этого не написано, значит нет такой рекомендации. Моя вам рекомендация, прямая: не занимайтесь демотивированием участников, отвечающих на вопросы.

Comment: @insolor, я логическую связь вижу, а объективно измеримые показатели аналитического мышления у меня высокие. Если что-то не рекомендовано, то и поощрять это не надо. Но хорошо, не буду "демотивировать" никого из отвечающих, какие бы вещи они не писали.

Comment: @Сергей это тут случай, когда не нужно применять особые аналитические способности, нужно читать что написано в правилах. У нас объективно не так много отвечающих, чтобы путем применения аналитических способностей из существующих правил выводить новые запретительные. Нужно наоборот поощрять участников давать ответы (ну кроме совсем некачественных), а не демотивировать новыми нигде не прописанными запретами.